# Trying to determine day of week first day of month falls on using Dart

Tags: date, calendar, format, dart

I'm using Dart to make a simple event calendar, and I'm wanting to determine which day of the week the 1st day of each month falls on.  So I have this function....

```dart
int FirstDayOfMonthFallsOnThisDayOfWeek(int year, int month) {
  int DayOfWeek = 0;
  DateTime theDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  DateFormat df = new DateFormat('E');
  switch(df.format(theDate).toUpperCase()) {
    case "SUNDAY":
      DayOfWeek = 1;
      break;
    case "MONDAY":
      DayOfWeek = 2;
      break;
    case "TUESDAY":
      DayOfWeek = 3;
      break;
    case "WEDNESDAY":
      DayOfWeek = 4;
      break;
    case "THURSDAY":
      DayOfWeek = 5;
      break;
    case "FRIDAY":
      DayOfWeek = 6;
      break;
    case "SATURDAY":
      DayOfWeek = 7;
      break;
  }
  return DayOfWeek;
}
```

And to use the DateFormat, I have...

```dart
import 'package:intl/date_format.dart';
```

And of-course I'm importing intl in my pubspec.yaml.  However, when I run this I get an error...

```
Internal error: '.../dart/cdkCalendar/web/out/packages/intl/date_format.dart':     
Error: line 5 pos 6: url expected
part of intl;
```

Is this a bug with this package?  Or am I doing something wrong that I'm not seeing.  Also, if someone knows a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, that would be greatly appreciated as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you get the error-message, but here is a simpler (untested) version:

```dart
int FirstDayOfMonthFallsOnThisDayOfWeek(int year, int month) {
  // Use hours != 0 to avoid daylight-saving issues. Shouldn't be a
  // problem with the 1st of a month, but still good practice.
  return new DateTime(year, month, 1, 12).weekday;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Intl for that:

int FirstDayOfMonthFallsOnThisDayOfWeek(int year, int month) => new DateTime(year, month, 1).weekday;

Comment: Thanks, I finally found it and was going to post the answer, but I'm still new here so I wasn't able too for several hours.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out why I was getting the error - I can't import a "part".  However, when I tried importing "intl/intl.dart", I got several errors, so I'm assuming this library isn't finished maybe?  In any case I found that...

```dart
DateTime.weekday;
```

...will return the number of the day of the week that the month started on.  However it starts with Monday as 1.  I personally find that akward since every calendar I've ever seen starts on Sunday and historically sunday is the 1st day of the week.  So, in any case I just modified the function I have so that it corrects the day of the week starting on Sunday...

```dart
int _FirstDayOfMonthDayOfWeek() {
  DateTime theDate = new DateTime(_theDate.year, _theDate.month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  return (theDate.weekday == 7) ? 1 : theDate.weekday + 1;
}
```

Comment: Almost all non-US countries use Monday as first day of the week, and that's what ISO 8601 chose as first day of the week. If you want Sunday as first day just use modulo: weekday % 7 (possibly + 1 if you need 1-based weekdays).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
List<String> weekdays = [
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thurday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday',
  'Sunday'
];
var now = DateTime.parse(DateTime.now().toString()).weekday;
return weekdays[now];
```